# How to verifying google token in Ktor backend

Tags: kotlin, jwt, google-signin, ktor

I am building a Webb application where the user gets a google jwt token in the front end and sends it to the backend. The backend is written in Ktor but I cant manage to find any information on how to verify it with Kotlin/Ktor. I did find [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token) for Python/Java but I cant seem ty implement it for Ktor.

Is there any documentations I can use or anyone that is willing to show me how?

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add dependency on [Google API Client Library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/blob/main/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleIdTokenVerifier.java) ?

I would also try to consider the possibility [server-side auth using ktor](https://ktor.io/docs/oauth.html#configure-oauth-provider)

Comment: Well, the first option option is in java and I cant get the imports to work. Cant find the dependency to use. So I assume it doesn't exist in kotlin/ktor. (could ofc be wrong)

Regarding the second option is that I already have the IDToken at the back end and i should be able to use it to know if it is real or not. I know that there is the 

"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=<accessToken>" link, and i am trying to get that one to work, but I dont seem to get the accesToken variabel rigth formated. (or rigth variabel)